# What would be the correct way of writing this for beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How would I pull the "We're sorry" text from here

```
<div class="c-capr-add__input-na">
                We're sorry. This product is not available online at this time.
            </div>
```

and place it like

```
return out_of_stock_divs.text == "We're sorry. This product is not available online at this time."
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: use one of the find_element_by methods, then get_text()

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have only html, so I will start from that part:

```
html = """<div class="c-capr-add__input-na">
                We're sorry. This product is not available online at this time.
            </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

Here we find *div* with the desired class. This returns list of elements matching the options, in this case, we have only one, so we choose 0-th index:

```
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'c-capr-add__input-na'})[0]
```

Now we only need to get text and stripit because it can have leading/trailing spaces and line breaks:

```
txt = div.getText()
clean_txt = txt.strip()
```

You can do whatever you want with `clean_txt`.